# Made some change that now gives an error when trying to close a Toplevel

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

At some point I changed something where I now get this error when trying to close a Toplevel() with .destroy() after clicking a button. I saw one fix that used a lambda function but I never ended up getting it to work.
Full Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 61, in login_verification
  File "<string>", line 73, in login_success
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2366, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"
```

Line 61 is the end of an if/else tree that calls `login_success`, line 73 is the button that calls for the `delete_popup` function.
Code that gives the error (there are actually 3 functions but they're all the same minus some label text)

```
def login_success(self):
        popup_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
        popup_screen.title("Success!")
        popup_screen.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        Label(popup_screen, text = "Login was successful.")
        Button(popup_screen, text = "Ok", command = self.delete_popup(popup_screen))

def delete_popup(self, x):
        x.destroy()
```

Comment: Should be `command=lambda: self.delete_popup(popup_screen)`.

Comment: Or simply `command=popup_screen.destroy`.

Comment: The reason I didn't think to try just `popup_screen.destroy` was because most of the time it spits out an error code but doesn't actually crash. But this time it didn't so thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to your problem.

1. Don't use a function, Simply pass `popup_screen.destroy` to the `Button` as the `command`.
2. Use `lambda` when you pass your function(`delete_popup`) to the `Button` as the `command`.

   - The parenthesis`()` cause the function to execute at the point where passed as `command` to the `Button`.
   - If you have to pass a function which doesn't have any argument you don't need these parenthesis`()`.
   - If arguments are to be passed to the function(Like in your case), You have to use `lambda` which stops the function to be executed at that point, so you can pass your arguments to it. Like This:

   ```
   def login_success(self):
       popup_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
       popup_screen.title("Success!")
       popup_screen.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

       Label(popup_screen, text="Login was successful.")
       Button(popup_screen, text="Ok", command=lambda: self.delete_popup(popup_screen))


   def delete_popup(self, x):
       x.destroy()
   ```

**Note:** Your indentation in the question is not correct. Hope you have corrected it in the actual code.